# Change Button's color twice when it's clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm trying to create a button whose change background color (to green) when it is cliked. But when it is cliked againg the button returns to the original background color (from orange).

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn-1")

if (btn1.style.backgroundColor = "orange") {
        btn1.addEventListener("click", function () {
        btn1.style.backgroundColor = "green"
    })
} else {btn1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    btn1.style.backgroundColor = "orange"
})
    }
```

Could you help me? Thx!

I'm trying to create a button whose change background color (to green) when it is cliked. But when it is cliked againg the button returns to the original background color (from orange).

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22191000/12484067

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: You should have a single event handler here, not several with a dependency on CSS styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.style.backgroundColor = "orange";

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if(button.style.backgroundColor == "orange"){
           button.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        } else button.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
})
```

```html
<button id="button">test</button>
```

how i understand you: you can set starter color of button to orange;
and then add EventListener to button with this logic:
-if the color of the button is `orange` - change to `green`
or if the color is not `orange` - change to `orange`

Comment: addEventListener is listener who listen when event will be, not when you are calling it like a regular function

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. My preferred way is simply toggle a class on the element.

In CSS set the default color via **#btn-1** then have an active color set via **#btn-1.active**. Then by toggling the class of active, you change the color to green when the element has the class of active, and orange when it doesn't.

```js
var toggleBTN = document.getElementById("btn-1")

toggleBTN.addEventListener("click",() => {
  toggleBTN.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
#btn-1{
  background:orange;
}

#btn-1.active{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-1">Toggle Color</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle the color on the click event:

```js
document
  .getElementById("btn-1")
  .addEventListener(
    'click', 
    ({target:{style}}) => style.backgroundColor = style.backgroundColor === 'orange' ? 'green' : 'orange'
  );
```

```html
<button id="btn-1" style="background-color: orange">Click me</button>
```

Comment: You should always explain your answer. Don't assume the OP or future visitors will understand what you did without one.